# JS colon expression `a:b:c:d=>0`

Tags: javascript

While declaring a lambda (a=b=>0) I inverted the equal sign with a colon.
To my surprise, the expression was correctly parsed.
So what does the colon mean ? since it's neither a ternary expression nor an object declaration.

```
a:b:c:d=>0
```

Thanks

Comment: It's a label. Normally in other languages labels are to be used with `goto` but js does not have `goto`. However, js do have goto-like keywords: `break` and `continue`. If you have a `switch` statement or `for` loop or any other syntax where `break` is legal nearby you can do `break a` and basically have your code goto `a`

Comment: https://astexplorer.net/ is your friend for code you do not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined 3 labels and one nameless function. It's equivalent to this:

```
a:
b:
c:
(d) => { return 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a [labeled function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). `a`, `b`, and `c` are all labels to the anonymous function `(d) => { return 0; }`. Although I haven't seen people use multiple labels on the same function before. Typical use cases are more like this:

```js
L: function F() {}
```

Comment: It is not a “labeled function declaration” – there is no such thing. The above code defines 3 labels: `a`, `b`, and `c`, and an arrow function expression – not assigned to anything.

Comment: I understand it's not technically a declaration, you're right. I simply copied the term “labeled function declaration” from MDN docs.

Answer (score 0):

These are three [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). Although every statement can be labeled, it only makes sense to label nested loops:

```
 outer: while(true) {
   while(true) {
     continue outer;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`a:` is a label. You can see for your self if you enter your snippet here: https://esprima.org/demo/parse.html

Labels are from back when `goto` was considered a good idea.

In JS you can (you shouldn't, but you can) use lables with `continue` statements.

```js
xLoop: for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
    if (y > 3) {
      continue xLoop;
    }
    console.log(x, y);
  }
}
```